Example and intuition for Hartshorne exercise II.2.14(c)
Hartshorne's exercise II.2.14(c) has the reader prove that if $\varphi : S \to T$ is a graded homomorphism of graded rings, and $\varphi_d : S_d \to T_d$ is an isomorphism for all $d \geq d_0$, then the induced morphism $f : \operatorname{Proj T} \to \operatorname{Proj S}$ is an isomorphism.
I was able to prove the result, but I feel like I'm lacking intuition about what this should tell me about projective spaces/the proj construction. I think that an example might help me find this geometric intuition. Can anyone give an example of a graded ring homomorphism that is an isomorphism only in sufficiently large degrees? Even better would be an explanation of the geometric intuition behind the example.

I don't have an example in mind (let alone a geometric interpretation) but another observation (that you probably already know), is that $\mathrm{Proj}T=\emptyset$ if and only if the irrelevant ideal $T_+$ is nilpotent. So my understanding is that the higher grades do determine the whole proj.

For an explicit example, consider the inclusion
$ k[x^2,x^3] \rightarrow k[x] $
or more generally, given any graded ring $S = \bigoplus S_i$ we can take the graded ring $R$ where we let $R_0 = S_0$, then $R_i = 0$ for $0 < i < n$ (for some $n$ that we pick) and $R_i = S_i$ for $i \geq n$. Then the natural map $R \rightarrow S$ has the desired property.
I'm not sure I have a good geometric intuition for this but I can at least explain one important use of this fact. Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ be a closed subvariety of projective space. Then we have a short exact sequence
$$ 0 \rightarrow \mathcal{I}_X \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow 0 $$
By Serre vanishing (III.5.2) for all $n$ sufficiently large, we get a short exact sequence
$$ 0 \rightarrow \Gamma(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{I}_X(n)) \rightarrow \Gamma(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(n)) \rightarrow \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X(n)) \rightarrow 0 $$
Let
$$ S = \bigoplus_{n \geq 0} \Gamma(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(n))/\Gamma(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{I}_X(n)) $$
be the homogeneous coordinate ring of $X$ and let
$$ R = \bigoplus_{n \geq 0} \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X(n)) $$
Then what we showed with Serre vanishing is that the map $S \rightarrow R$ is an isomorphism in all large degrees. Therefore
$$ X = \text{Proj } S = \text{Proj } R $$
This can be very useful since $R$ only depends on the line bundle $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$ on $X$.
